# How to get PDF chapter information with CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf

Any sample code I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See “Outline” in /Developer/Examples/Quartz/PDF.